# Allow users to join public or private groups in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have 'groups' in my Meteor application that users can join. On the groups page I show a list of users who have joined. Im publishing this like so:

```
Meteor.publish("allUsers", function() {
  return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {name: 1, groups: 1}});
});
```

However id also like users to have the option of join groups publicly or privately. The only way I can think to do this would be to have another field for privately joined groups that is only published to the current user:

```
Meteor.publish('currentUser', function() {
  return Meteor.users.find(
    { _id: this.userId },
    { fields: { name: 1, groups: 1, groups-private: 1 } },
  );
});
```

This will allow me to show the current user any groups they have joined privately, and also show the public groups data.

However this approach has its limitations. I cant show the total number of members of a group, any private members cannot be counted. How can I get round this? Do I need to store numbers on the groups collection? Im concerned about getting race conditions if I do this.

Comment: How are ```groups``` and ```groups-private``` structured? Is it just an array of group names? Maybe you can  have a separate collection like you suggested, and have an observer running on allUsers. If a user document is newly inserted or changed or deleted, increment or decrement the count via the observer accordingly.

Comment: Basically yes, the groups and groups-private field on the user is an array of IDs which relate to groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of modeling you have a many-to-many relationship between users and groups but the relationship *itself* has properties, i.e. it can be public or private. One could imagine you wanting to track other properties of that relationship in the future such as `joinedDate`.

Instead of storing an array of `groupId` *strings* in the user document you can store an array of *objects* that include the extra properties. For one user this could look like:

```
groups = [
  { groupId: 1, public: true },
  { groupId: 2, public: false },
  { groupId: 3 } // or just omit the public value altogether (default is private)
  ...
]
```

If you want to publish all the *public* members of a group to a user you can then do:

```
Meteor.publish('publicUsersOfGroup',function(groupId){
  check(groupId,String);
  if (this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find({ groups: { $elemMatch: { groupId: groupId, public: true }});
  }
  this.ready();
});
```

If you want to count members of a group you can then do:

```
const publicCount = Meteor.users.find({ groups: { $elemMatch: { groupId: groupId, public: true }}).count();
const privateCount = Meteor.users.find({ groups: { $elemMatch: { groupId: groupId, public: {$ne: true }}).count();
const totalCount = Meteor.users.find({ groups: { $elemMatch: { groupId: groupId }).count();
```

For performance you'll want to index both those array object keys.